# How to solve this momentum equation?

Tags: momentum, velocity

I am currently learning momentum, but I find two equations in my textbook with no proof.

Equation 1:

final velocity of:

$$\text{final velocity of }A = \frac{\text{initial velocity of} \  A \times (\text{mass} \ A - \text{mass} \ B)}{(\text{mass} \ A + \text{mass} \ B)}$$

Equation 2:

$$\text{final velocity of} \ B = \frac{\text{initial velocity of} \ A \times 2 (\text{Mass} \ A)}{(\text{Mass} \ A + \text{Mass} \ B)}$$

The textbook said this equation can be used in a perfectly elastic collision of two objects, but I don't want to force myself to memorise it, I want to prove and understand it, but I can't.

Comment: Did you notice that the formulas are not symmetric and that there is no initial velocity of B? What does that tell you?

Comment: the initial velocity of B is being cancelled by some method? :/

Comment: It means that the initial velocity of B was assumed to be zero. Start with that.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thanks! I got it!

Comment: You may also want to look at the center-of-mass reference frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the initial velocities of A and B as $u_A, u_B$; their final velocities as $v_A, v_B$; and their masses as $m_A, m_B$. By conservation of momentum we know that

$m_Au_A + m_Bu_B = m_Av_A + m_B v_B$

and, since the collision is elastic, we can use conservation of energy to get

$\displaystyle \frac 1 2 m_Au_A^2 + \frac 1 2 m_Bu_B^2  = \frac 1 2 m_Av_A^2 + \frac 1 2 m_B v_B^2$

If we work in a reference frame in which B is initially stationary then we can set $u_B=0$, which gives us

$m_A(u_A -v_A) = m_B v_B
\\ m_A(u_A^2 - v_A^2)  = m_B v_B^2$

Dividing one equation by the other gives us

$u_A+v_A = v_B$

and using this equation to substitute for $v_B$ in the conservation of momentum equation gives us

$m_Au_A = m_Av_A + m_B(u_A + v_A)
\\ \Rightarrow v_A(m_A +m_B) = u_A(m_A-m_B)$

Rearranging this equation gives your textbook's Equation 1, and adding $u_A$ to both sides then gives your textbook's Equation 2.

Comment: Oh, the proof is so simple! Thanks a lot!